# LibGDX - Basic 2D lighting, don't know what to do

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

It's my first time attempting to create a basic light system that uses a black texture with a white circle on top. I read various threads about the issue but I just don't know what I am doing wrong.

What I want is the ambient to be dark and the light to be well white but changing the spritebatch color to something darker will cause the light to be darker to EVEN if I reset the color when drawing the light texture

So this is what I want (did this by forcing the light texture draw 5 times but that isn't a solution, it's an hack):
[image: what I get if I draw the light 5 times while darkening the screen]

This is what I get (only 1 light texture is drawn but isn't very visible):
[image: what I get while darkening the spritebatch and resetting the color to draw the light]

This is what I get without darkening the spritebatch: 
[image: what I get by drawing the light without darkening the spritebatch]

Main code:

```
Game.sb.begin();
//Make stuff darker
Game.sb.setColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f,1f);
sb.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
lvl.render();
//Reset color
Game.sb.setColor(1f, 1f, 1f,1f);
sb.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_DST_COLOR, GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA);
//This draws all lights by drawing a texture with the above blending function
lightM.render();
Game.sb.end();
```

Light object draw method:

```
Game.sb.setColor(c.r,c.b,c.g, 1f);
Utils.drawTexture(Assets.get("sprites/lightcircle2.png", Texture.class), pos, size, true);
Game.sb.setColor(1,1,1,1);
```

Am I making some kind of error with the setcolor? I been considering using a FrameBuffer but I am not sure if it will give me the light effect I want

By the way this is my light texture (it's CC0):

[image: lighttexture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement by these ways :

1. By using Shaders. [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JkyGTZ0992s) is a small video and [article](http://www.alcove-games.com/opengl-es-2-tutorials/lightmap-shader-fire-effect-glsl/) on that video.
2. By use FBO and Blending, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45598754/3445320) is one of my answer on this topic.
3. You can use [box2dlight](https://github.com/libgdx/box2dlights), even without using box2dbody(if you don't want any shadows)

   ```
   World world = new World(new Vector2(0,0),false);
   RayHandler rayHandler = new RayHandler(world);
   rayHandler.setCombinedMatrix(stage.getCamera().combined);   //<-- pass your camera combined matrix
   new PointLight(rayHandler,1000, Color.WHITE,radius,x_position,y_position);
   ```

   And at last call `rayHandler.updateAndRender();` after all your rendering in your `render()` method.

Comment: I will try to use FBO and blending, GLSL seems complicated and I dont want to use box2dlights. Thanks! :D

Comment: broken article link: https://web.archive.org/web/20171031231217/http://www.alcove-games.com/opengl-es-2-tutorials/lightmap-shader-fire-effect-glsl/